# Using same hash, why is data not overwritten after hash ref assigned?

Tags: perl

I have written a routine that builds up a complex data structure using hashes.

```
use strict;
my %th1 = ();
my %th2 = ();
my $idx = 0;

$th2{"suffix"} = "A";
$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 42;

$th1{$idx} = \%th2;

$idx++;

$th2{"suffix"} = "B";
$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 105;

$th1{$idx} = \%th2;

for my $key1 (keys %th1)
{
    for my $key2 (keys %{$th1{$key1}})
    {
        print "Key1=$key1, Key2=$key2, value=" . $th1{$key1}->{$key2} . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

My question is, when a hash reference is assigned, why isn't the first set of data at `$idx == 0` corrupted?

Has there been a copy created when the hash ref is assigned `$th1{$idx} = \%th2;`?

When this line is executed

`$th2{"suffix"} = "B";`

why aren't the hash values at `$th1{0}` corrupted?

The values are not corrupted, but I'm curious as to the mechanism that preserves these values. The code has not explicitly created a new copy of `%th2`. So, what is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of this program is:

```
Key1=1, Key2=status, value=0

Key1=1, Key2=suffix, value=B

Key1=1, Key2=consumption, value=105

Key1=0, Key2=status, value=0

Key1=0, Key2=suffix, value=B

Key1=0, Key2=consumption, value=105
```

If you see something different when you run it, please indicate what you see.

There is no corruption, nor copying being done.  `%th1` contains pointers to a single other hash.

There is one hash at one memory location, and another hash at another.  As you modify `%th2`, it changes.

Modifying this a little bit so that I can have a more compact output and be able to call display as a function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %th1 = ();
my %th2 = ();

$th2{"suffix"} = "A";
$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 42;
$th1{0} = \%th2;

print "--- After first block:\n";
display(\%th1);


$th2{"suffix"} = "B";

print "--- Modified th2 suffix to B:\n";
display(\%th1);

$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 105;

print "--- finished modification of th2:\n";
display(\%th1);

$th1{1} = \%th2;

print "--- after assignment to th1{1} :\n";
display(\%th1);

exit;

sub display {
    my $hr = shift;
    for my $key1 (keys %$hr) {
        print "$key1:\n";
        for my $key2 (keys %{$hr->{$key1}}) {
            print "\t$key2 = $hr->{$key1}{$key2}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
--- After first block:
0:
        status = 0
        suffix = A
        consumption = 42
--- Modified th2 suffix to B:
0:
        status = 0
        suffix = B
        consumption = 42
--- finished modification of th2:
0:
        status = 0
        suffix = B
        consumption = 105
--- after assignment to th1{1} :
1:
        status = 0
        suffix = B
        consumption = 105
0:
        status = 0
        suffix = B
        consumption = 105
```

You can see the modifications to `%th2` taking effect in the dereferenced values in `%th1`.

Lets look at this differently... instead of printing out the values, lets just print out what `%th1` contains?  Two changes... the addition of the line to show memory near the top:

```
my %th1 = ();
my %th2 = ();

print \%th1, "\t", \%th2,"\n";  # this line added
```

and `display` changed:

```
sub display {
    my $hr = shift;
    for my $key1 (keys %$hr) {
        print "$key1 --> $hr->{$key1}\n";
    }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
HASH(0x239edb0) HASH(0x239edf8)
--- After first block:
0 --> HASH(0x239edf8)
--- Modified th2 suffix to B:
0 --> HASH(0x239edf8)
--- finished modification of th2:
0 --> HASH(0x239edf8)
--- after assignment to th1{1} :
1 --> HASH(0x239edf8)
0 --> HASH(0x239edf8)
```

The values of `%th1` point to a single hash all the way through.  No copies, just one hash that is changed behind the back of `%th1`.

---

Chances are, you want separate values at each spot.  This is most easily done by creating an anonymous hash and assigning that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %th1 = ();
my %th2 = ();

$th1{0} = {"suffix" => "A", "status" => 0, "consumption" => 42 };

print "--- After first block:\n";
display(\%th1);

$th1{1} = {"suffix" => "B", "status" => 0, "consumption" => 105 };

print "--- after assignment to th1{1} :\n";
display(\%th1);

exit;

sub display {
    my $hr = shift;
    for my $key1 (keys %$hr) {
        print "$key1: $hr->{$key1}\n";
        for my $key2 (keys %{$hr->{$key1}}) {
            print "\t$key2 = $hr->{$key1}{$key2}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
--- After first block:
0: HASH(0xcf6998)
        status = 0
        suffix = A
        consumption = 42
--- after assignment to th1{1} :
1: HASH(0xd143c0)
        status = 0
        suffix = B
        consumption = 105
0: HASH(0xcf6998)
        status = 0
        suffix = A
        consumption = 42
```

You can see two separate memory addresses and two separate sets of values.

Comment: This is the answer I was seeking `There is one hash at one memory location, and another hash at another. As you modify %th2, it changes.`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the values are being copied? If I run your code I get the 
following output (with blank lines removed):

```
Key1=1, Key2=status, value=0
Key1=1, Key2=suffix, value=B
Key1=1, Key2=consumption, value=105
Key1=0, Key2=status, value=0
Key1=0, Key2=suffix, value=B
Key1=0, Key2=consumption, value=105
```

This is exactly what I'd expect and shows that no copying is being done, going 
through either hash reference yields the same results.

Comment: By copying I mean another %th2 is being created behind the scenes once it's been altered. Hence, it's at another memory location.

Comment: That's definitely NOT happening.

Answer (score 0):

Mea Culpa. I appreciate everyone's patience, as I'm re-learning Perl again for the first time. I asked the wrong question in the OP.

I should have asked how a dynamic variable is created, so its reference, a unique reference to a new hash variable, can be assigned to another hash variable. The straight-line code I wrote in the OP won't work, as people have commented.

The following -- which I have tested and works -- is what I wound up doing. Not knowing Perl internals, I am assuming a new dynamic variable is created each time this statement executes: (Please be advised the code sample below is what the OP's sample morfed into.)

`my %read_data = ();`

And each time `$tiered_cns{$idx} = \%read_data;` is executed, the reference is to a different variable.

```
sub ws_get_cons_from_latest_read

# $PkNam Package name. We disregard it.
# $DBHdl --  ICS database handle.
# $acct_no -- water acct number (integer)
# $time_stamp -- usually this value is today's date as a year to second
{
# Grab input parameters.
my ($PkNam, $DBHdl, $acct_no, $time_stamp) = @_;

# Declare local variables.
my $ptSelHdl = undef;
my $ptMtrRecRef = undef;
my $ptWsMtrReadRecRef = undef;

my $consumption = 0;
my $statement = "";
my %tiered_cns = ();
my $idx = undef;

die("wgbl_get_cons_from_latest_read passed undef handles.")
  if(!defined($DBHdl) || !defined($acct_no));

$statement = "select    m.* ".
             "from      meter m ".
             "where     m.acct_no = ".$acct_no;

$ptSelHdl = $DBHdl->prepare($statement);

if(!$ptSelHdl || !$ptSelHdl->execute)
{
  die("Could not prepare select suffix numdigits from meter statement.");
} 

$ptMtrRecRef = $ptSelHdl->fetchrow_hashref;

$idx = 0;

if(!defined($ptMtrRecRef))
{
  my %read_data = ();
  $read_data{"status"} = MISSING_METER_REC;
  $read_data{"suffix"} = " ";
  $read_data{"consumption"} = 0;
  $tiered_cns{$idx} = \%read_data;
}
else
{
  do
  {
    my %read_data = ();

    $ptWsMtrReadRecRef = MtrGblFunc->mgbl_get_latest_ws_mtr_rec($DBHdl,
                        $ptMtrRecRef->{"acct_no"},
                        $ptMtrRecRef->{"suffix"});


    if(!$ptWsMtrReadRecRef)
    {
      $read_data{"status"} = MISSING_LATEST_READ;
      $read_data{"suffix"} = $ptMtrRecRef->{"suffix"};
      $read_data{"consumption"} = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      $consumption = WsGblFunc->wgbl_calc_mtr_cons( $DBHdl,
                     $acct_no,
                     $ptMtrRecRef->{"suffix"},
                     $ptWsMtrReadRecRef->{"counter"},
                     $ptWsMtrReadRecRef->{"reading"},
                     $ptWsMtrReadRecRef->{"date_read"},
                     $time_stamp); 

      $read_data{"status"} = SUCCESS;
      $read_data{"suffix"} = $ptMtrRecRef->{"suffix"};
      $read_data{"consumption"} = $consumption;

      $tiered_cns{$idx} = \%read_data;
      $idx++;

      $ptMtrRecRef = $ptSelHdl->fetchrow_hashref;

     }
    } until !defined($ptMtrRecRef) || !defined($ptWsMtrReadRecRef);
  }

   return \%tiered_cns;
}
```